# How to color sudoku with this added constraint?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, colorings, sudoku

I couldn't figure out an algorithm for following graph coloring problem:

**Output color of each vertex for this graph:** 
Given  a solved 9*9 sudoku board that is a 9-colored board, applied first three rules below( a 4*4 one is in the picture as example), 
 
Output a new k-coloring(k > 9) for the graph made from the input when we also applied rule number four.
**Edge incidence rules:**
 1. There exists an edge between every pair of cells that are in the same row.

2. There exists an edge between every pair of cells that are in the same column.
3. There exists an edge between every pair of cells that are in the same 3*3 square.
4. There exists an edge between every pair of cells that have the same label in the input board, that is an edge connects every cell labeled with number 1 to every other cell with the label 1, and every 2 is connected to any other 2s, and ...
   [image]
   **Edit:**

   I wondered whether there is an algorithm with tighter upper bound on k than the usual greed algorithm or not.
   (The greedy algorithm's upper bound on k is maximum of degrees of vertices of the graph plus one) 
   Till now I just figured out that the subgraph that contains each color in the input is a clique when the rule four applied, That is there is a clique with vertices labeled 1, a clique with vertices all labeled 2, and so on.Since there is an edge between every pair of vertices with the same label so they are all connected, thus we have a complete subgraph, i.e. clique.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.  What is the output?

Comment: @AndrásSalamon From what I understand: the input is a solved 9*9 sudoku that is represented by a 9-coloring of a graph that is built using edge rule 1, 2 and three. I think OP wants to design an algorithm that fixes the current coloring to a k-coloring ($k \geq 9$) when edge rule 4 is applied to said graph since applying rule 4 will violate (or maybe not?) the input graph coloring. This new coloring would then represent a 9*9 sodoku that uses more than 9 numbers.

Comment: Although the question is somewhat unclear, I think this is a very interesting problem! Where did you find this? Did you come up with this on your own? It looks like you're trying to create a harder variant of Sudoku.

Comment: In a solved 9*9 Sudoku, each number will occur 9 times. If you add edge rule 4, each number will have 8 neighbouring numbers that are the same and thus voilating the coloring. If you change these 8 neughbours to random, unique values. Your coloring will be fixed. Or are you looking for minimal colorings? You didn't specify that. Why not use off the shelf graph coloring algorithms? e.g. http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1014496509129

Comment: Rule 4 defines so-called orthogonal squares.

Comment: @Auberon Thank you for explanation, You got the problem perfectly. This problem stated to me by a sophomore in computer science( I'm a senior student) , I liked it, I think writing a program that outputs the new coloring were their semester project for Graph theory class.